# Strange output about jQuery

Tags: jquery

---

```
var message = 'Spoon!';
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
alert(message);
});

message = 'Not in the face!';
$('#bar').bind('click', function() {
alert(message);
});
```

---

Why are the two output messages are the same: "Not in the face!";
Isn't the first message within the closure of 'foo' refers to 'Spoon!'?
Why not?
Please someone explain. I don't understand the tutorial's explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the event handlers are launched asynchronously.
While the message value you're setting is done in the first thread.

So basically your program will read your whole code, set the value to `'Spoon!'`, then to the last one you set `'Not in the face!'`. Then when you click on either buttons it'll alert the value of message `'Not in the face!'`.

Try putting message in the function, then you'll see a different message for each. This would work as you expect as you set also the value asynchronously.

```
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
  var message = 'Spoon!';
  alert(message);
});

$('#bar').bind('click', function() {
  var message = 'Not in the face!';
  alert(message);
});
```

Comment: Oh. I got it... The compiler would set the variable "message" to "Not in the face!" first. And as one of the two buttons is triggered, it get the value 'Not in the face'. Is that correct? Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

When `foo` is clicked, it will alert the last value of `message`, which will be "Not in the face!" as this line of code has already been executed when the page was loading.

Answer (score 0):

only binding of the function happens .The actual execution of code happens when the click evenet occurs.When the click event occues the message variable will its last value which is 'Not in face'

Answer (score 0):

```
// below you are estblishing the "variable" message and setting it to the String "Spoon!"
var message = 'Spoon!';
// Here you use the jquery method to tell a button with the ID "foo" 
//    to alert the variable "message"
$('#foo').bind('click', function() {
    alert(message);    //    the alert
});

//  Here's where you're getting confused
//Below you are "re-asigning the variable "message" to be the String "Not in the face!"
message = 'Not in the face!';
// below is another click bind to a button, but this time the id name is "bar"
// so both buttons (foo and bar) are committing the same action, 
// but your variable has been changed to "Not in the face!" and therefor
//  will never display "Spoon!"
$('#bar').bind('click', function() {
    alert(message);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, SpYk3HH. I got it!